# WPF Databinding stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, stackpanel

Im a beginner in WPF programming, coming from .NET 2.0 C#.

Im trying to make a horizontal `StackPanel` which should be filled with data from a table in a database. The problem is that I want it to display an image with some text from the table below and then stack those two items horizontally.

Here's some pseudo-code to display what I want to do:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="horizontal" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myTable}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="User.png"/>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=UserName}"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I simply cannot figure oout how to do this.

Answer (score 34):

Julien's answer is correct for your written description, however, looking at your XAML, it appears you are looking for something like the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="User.png"/>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl x:Name="UserList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You definately need an ItemsControl (or some derivation of) to bind your source to. Then you can change the the orientation by setting it's items panel (which I believe is a VirtualizingStackPanel with Vertical orientation by default) so just set it to a VirtualizingStackPanel with Horizontal Orientation. Then you can set the ItemsTemplate for each of your items to the layout you desire (an image stacked on top of text bound from your database).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, your examples was exactly what i needed!

Comment: This should be the first lesson of every XAML book/tutorial ever written.

Answer (score 29):

Basically, you want to use a control capable of displaying an enumeration of objects. The control capable of this is the class `ItemsControl` and all of its descendants (`Selector`, `ListBox`, `ListView`, etc).

Bind the `ItemsSource` property of this control to a list of objects you want, here a list of users you've fetched from the database. Set the `ItemTemplate` of the control to a `DataTemplate` that will be used to display each item in the list.

Sample code:

In a `Resources` section (for example `Window.Resources`):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="User.png"/>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In your `Window`/`Page`/`UserControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="UserList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" />
```

In your code behind:

```
UserList.ItemsSource = ... // here, an enumeration of your Users, fetched from your db
```