# How to use data binding to display items as a stack

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Is there a way in C#, to dynamically build somehow a stack of items?
Just like a list, but without that scrolling and selecting.

I am searching a way to stack items from a list via binding.

And now I want to do this with a stack.

Comment: what is wrong with Stack ? I mean you can just make a generic stack of objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx

Comment: Don't you scroll through a list and eventually select an item of it?

Comment: If you want a List that doesn't scroll and select, then use a List. It doesn't scroll and select.

Comment: I think he is referring to a stack-like UI and not stack data structure. is this WPF or Windows form ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. It's called ItemsControl and it has no ScrollViewing + selecting.
YOu can do it like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemssSource="{Binding items}">
</ItemsControl>
```

you probably need to change ItemsControl.ItemTemplate and ItemsControl.ItemPanelsTemplate

Comment: Just like here I guess: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356719/bind-collection-to-stackpanel`