# Treeview "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

If I use the following code without `<DataTemplate>` it is working and I can see only the `SoftwareVersion`, when I add `<DataTemple>` throws an exception. Any idea why?

```
ObservableCollection<Note> AllNotes


<TreeView Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNotes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Note}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListIssuesType}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SoftwareVersion}" Margin="2" />
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IssueTypeName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741925/how-do-i-set-a-datatemplate-for-a-wpf-treeview-to-display-all-elements-of-an-lis

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear at all *why* you are adding a `DataTemplate` to your control. But it is clear why you are getting the exception: you have added the `DataTemplate` object as a direct child of the `TreeView`, which makes it an item in the `Items` collection. It's "template" nature becomes completely irrelevant; you are telling the control to just include that object as an element in the view.

And of course, now that the `Items` collection is non-empty, you are not allowed to send the `ItemsSource` property.

So the fix for the exception is "don't do that". I.e. stop trying to make the `DataTemplate` element an item in the tree view's list of items.

Beyond that, there's not enough context in your question to say how you *should* be using the `DataTemplate` object. Presumably you intend it to be used as part of the template for an actual data item in the tree view; maybe it needs to be incorporated into the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` somehow.

But without more specifics regarding exactly what the code does now and what you want it to do instead, as well as you providing a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) clearly illustrating your scenario, I don't see a good way to address that part of your problem. If you still need help with defining the data template, please post a new question that provides the necessary details.