# Set TreeViewItem Header text color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a XAML and its ModelView class to bind some information and basic layout properties such as foreground colors.

The TreeViewItem has a header text that can be black or red, depending on the MV property.

The problem is that **the Foreground property affects to the whole TreeViewItem**, and I just want the header to be red or black.

Here the piece of XAML that defines the foreground binding:

```
<TreeView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding GridResultCollection}"
        Focusable="True">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <TreeViewItem 
                Header="{Binding Name}" 
                Foreground="{Binding Path=PassedAllValues}" 
                IsExpanded="True">
                <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                   Text="Type:"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=TypeValue}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Path=TypeForeground}"/>
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I think You are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17787900/5159725)

Comment: You need to define TreeViewItem HeaderTemplate and create the datagrigger that changes your foreground there.