# Bind subitems along with main items to same control WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

How can we bind an object List to a control with its main items and sub items. If the class structure is like this

```
public class BookChapter
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<BookPage> Pages {get; set; }
 public List<String> Questions { get; set; }

}
public class BookPage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<String> Excercises { get; set; }
}
```

How can i bind it on a WPF control with ChapterName and Pages associated with every chapters in a single control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this in WPF, one way would involve the use of `DataTemplates` to describe how you would like your objects to be displayed. Using `ItemsControl` or derived controls to hold display your collections:

I often separate my styles into various types to make them slightly easier to read e.g:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Book Chapters -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BookChapter}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Book Pages -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BookPage}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Margin="5 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5 0"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Exercises}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Chapters}" />
</Grid>
```

Which will produce something that looks like this (based on what I populated your objects with):[image]

Without templating your objects, `WPF` will simply display the collections as `ApplicationName.ClassName` - the result of `ToString`, templates give you the ability to define how you would like your classes to be displayed.

You can hold these templates in a separate resource file, and reuse them across your application if required. It's important to note that because I'm templating the actual `Type`, this template will be used whenever your objects are displayed within this particular `Window`, unless you specify otherwise.

You can add greater control over when/were these templates are used, by naming them, and only applying them to specific components (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: How the values Ex1 , Ex2 are displayed on window? For me they are not showing . In Xaml i can't see any controls which is assigned to Excercise property  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Exercises}" /> .Will this line alone render all excercise values correctly or we need to design an extra textblock with Binding in xaml to show exercise ?

Comment: Since `Exercise` is just a string collection of `string`, the `ItemsControl` you listed will display the strings as above, the `ItemsControl` will automatically wrap the strings in a `TextBlock`. If you want to add further customisation, you can alter the `ItemContainerStyle`, or alter the `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` with a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Ah, the problem is the way you're spelling `Exercises`, I corrected the spelling when I was templating it and forgot to point it out.

Comment: Yes that was the problem...Thanks for pointing out that and now it works

Comment: Good stuff, apologies for the spelling confusion.

Comment: Can i present the same inside an ItemsControl? My aim is to show it as a list of items inside Stackpanel . Item Control layout is like http://pastebin.com/4jmKnn8v

Comment: That should be fine, this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356719/bind-collection-to-stackpanel