# How to display listbox items in column view in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Am using listbox control in WPF its display listbox item in row wise but I want to display in column wise ( Something like bootstrap grid)

XMAL

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_items">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                            
            <StackPanel Margin="10 0 0 0">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Am binding Listbox from code behind

```
lb_items.ItemsSource = modules.ToList();
```

Comment: I think that it's easier using an ItemControl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356719/bind-collection-to-stackpanel that a ListBox

Comment: Thanks bro , will try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lb_items">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 0 0 0">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks @vercin will try this one.

Comment: @basitraza can you mark it as a solution ? If it helps you.

Comment: Actually both of answer works , that's why am confused which one to mark :)

Comment: @basitraza Could you please `Mark` the `Response` that helped you most. It will be a sign of appreciating someone who helped you; moreover it will help other readers of this post, as well. Readers pay more attention when a response has been marked as an `Answer`. I was about to jump to the next search when I did not see any response to your post marked as an `Answer` - thinking the issue probably was not resolved,

Answer (score 1):

ListBox has property called ItemsPanel, which determines how items are rendered.

Somewhere in application resource create different ItemsPanelTemplate, so you can easily reuse it:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
    <WrapPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalStackPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

then you can easily use it:

```
<ListBox ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanelTemplate}">...
<ItemControl ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}">...
```

always put such assets into application resources in order to make the code for your views clean and readable.

---

**Extra Tip:**
Here is animated WrapPanel, that animates items, when you resize window or an item is inserted to the list:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="FluidWrapPanel">
    <WrapPanel>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
            </ei:FluidMoveBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </WrapPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

dont forget to include these xml namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Comment: Thanks @Liero will try this one.

Comment: This error message prompt in VS  "The name `FluidMoveBehavior` does not exits in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivit`"

Comment: Its works buddy , am not add `microsoft.expression.interactions.dll` in project reference set.